# In which way can I prevent constant redrawing of a tooltip

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, flot

I have a certain Flot graph and appended bootstrap tooltips to the datapoints.

Upon hovering and moving the mouse over an item the tooltip is constantly fading in. See the following jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dietervdf/fuwg9fn9/1/

I'm using the following code:

```
$('#placeholder').bind('plothover', function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
        var x = item.datapoint[0],
            y = item.datapoint[1];

        $('#box')
            .css({
            top: item.pageY - 2,
            left: item.pageX + 1
        })
            .tooltip({
            title: y,
            placement: 'top',
            html: true
        })
            .tooltip('show');
    } else {
        $('#box').tooltip('destroy');
    }
});
```

What is the best way to prevent this behaviour? I was thinking of using a global-like variable and remembering the last `(x,y)`-position. Something like:

```
if(global_x != x || global_y != y)
    then show and adjust global_x, global_y
```

But this seems like an ugly hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are showing the tooltip every time the `plothover` event is fired, the tooltip gets re-shown every time the mouse moves (even over the same point). This causes the flicker you are seeing.

If you initialize your tooltip outside of the `plothover` event and then check to see if a tooltip is visible (by checking for `$('.tooltip').length === 0`), you can decide if you need to actually show or just update the tooltip text. This gets rid of the flicker you are noticing:

```
if ($('.tooltip').length === 0) {
    $('#box').tooltip({
       title: "tooltip title"
    }).tooltip('show');
} else {
    $('#box').tooltip({
        title: "tooltip title"
    }).tooltip('fixTitle');
}
```

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuwg9fn9/2/) demonstrates the fix.

Comment: Thanks. What's the point of the second `.tooltip({title:"tooltip title"})`? The example is still working even if I remove this, meaning it's not necessary?

Comment: @dietervdf in case you wanted to change the tooltip text for some reason. Otherwise, you could remove it (you can actually remove the `else` part of the `if` statement if you don't want to change the text).